# Json date deserializer for gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I want to deserialize following json string in gson. 
What is the propper GsonBuilder setDateFormat string code?

```
{  
   "created_at":{  
      "date":"2016-07-10 18:58:34.000000"
   }
}

 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
...
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("???");
```

or any custom Date.class deserializer?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
gsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
```

This has all the details you need to [create your own pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).